# Wordpress woocommerce Downloadable digital products needs to work only after payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website with downloadable digital products(pdf) and after payment

I tried this code and working fine. but the problem is this file should be restricted to paid users only.

```
if (wc_customer_bought_product('', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id())) {
            $downloads = $product->get_downloads();
            foreach ($downloads as $key => $each_download) {
                echo '<a href="' . $each_download["file"] . '" class="btn btn-primary px-3" download> <strong class="ps-2" style="vertical-align:bottom">Download</strong></a>';
            }
        }
```

but this is accessible to all users through url.
When i use `Redirect only` option in woocommerce settings its opening for all users via link.
and if i use `Force downloads` option then its going to  `403 error` and even download also failed for paid users. I need a solu

[image]

Comment: You should investigate why you get 403. Force download prevents direct access to the link. Could be server side issue could be something else.

Comment: If i enable Redirect only option its working fine but file is available public. but if i chosse force downloads its giving 403. Cant we stop the opening file publicly in wordpress? any idea.

Comment: Like i said you have to use Force download to protect your files otherwise they will be "public" and will use the normal upload dir of WP where all files are public. While with Force your files are located in woocommerce_uploads. So if you get 403 error is probably server problem and you have to investigate.- read more here - https://woo.com/document/approved-download-directories/